# How To Lazy Load Components and Modules on Demand in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, dojo

I am trying to Develop Multitasking Web-app Like the screenshot i attached but , i cannot start coding because i could not understand how angular 2 loads Dependency(both component and service). my requirement is like this 
 -  A Tab Based Web-app where i can fire a process and it will be loaded on a TAB with its all dependency , the problem is i could have more than hundreds of process that i do not want to bloat NgModule Import i only want the modules or components to be loaded on a tab load event.

---

I just want a guide on a general system design with Angular 2, i have read dojo is mature with this kind of issue with just `require('modulename')` inside a click event or anywhere required but the problem is dojo is complicated but i will switch to that if angular does not support that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Lazy loaded Route Modules, Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

you may have something like below,

App routes

```
  {
    path: 'tab-path-1',
    loadChildren: 'app/tab1.module#Tab1Module'
  },
  {
    path: 'tab-path-2',
    loadChildren: 'app/tab2.module#Tab2Module'
  }
```

Tab1Module Routes

```
 { 
     path: '',   
     component: Tab1Component      
  }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: tabs dont have routes (path) how am i suppose to implement that

Comment: Are you using a custom component library for tabs, else if you are creating your own, you may implement and give it a link, Cheers!!

Comment: i am planning to use angular material 2, or primeng still not desided.

Comment: i heard angular 2 is comming with dynamic component loading , till then i am dropping angular 2 and going with requirejs with angular 1 in that way i can require my controllers on demand i.e when a new tab is loaded